usb 1-3: device descriptor read/64, error -71
There are periodically these messages from the usb port. And mouse stops working. After certain time everything is working again. Is it coming from Ubuntu, or old hardware?

Test your USB device on different hardware and see if you get a different result.

I plugged another mouse. Error is different: usb 1-3: device not accepting address 89, error -71

Check the Hub/port on which its being connected..    I briefly explored USB messages I see on this box, and for me the cause is a external powered USB 5-port hub... If I disconnect that device from the machine, all messages disappear, though as I don't currently have a replacement USB hub to use, I just reconnected it & am for now, just ignoring the messages.  My conclusion is the powered USB port of mine is faulty or failing..   if your mouse (or any device connected thru yours) stops working you have more proof of a failing device possibly!
